# Select JSON value from a EAV structure result set

Tags: postgresql, jsonb, entity-attribute-value

Given a result set which is in the EAV structure such as :

```
id   | attributeName  | stringValue | intValue  | BooleanValue
---------------------------------------------------------------
1       stringFoo            v1
1       stringFooList        v2   
1       stringFooList        v3
1       intFoo                           10
1       intFooList                       10
1       intFooList                       20
1       booleanFoo                                     true
1       booleanFooList                                 true 
1       booleanFooList                                 true
```

How can I select all the attributes and value pair as a single value in a JSON/JSONB format , which are something likes:

```
{
    "stringFoo"         : "v1" , 
    "stringFooList"     : ["v2","v3"] ,
    "intFoo"            : 10 ,
    "intFooList"        : [10,20],
    "booleanFoo"        : true,
    "booleanFooList"    : [true,true]
}
```

If there are multiple attribute value for an attribute such as `stringFooList` , it will format it as JSON array.

I am using PostgreSQL 9.6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`@a_horse_with_no_name` 's answer gives me a good start. I extend his/her answer and come up the following query such that the elements in the JSON array have the same data type of  what defined in PostgreSQL.

```
select id, jsonb_object_agg(att, 
    case 
      when strval is not null then strval
      when intvalue is not null then intvalue
      else boolVal
     end 
    )
from (
  select id, 
         attributename as att,  
         case when count(*) > 1 then 
            jsonb_agg(stringvalue) filter (where stringvalue is not null) 
         else 
            to_jsonb(min(stringvalue) filter (where stringvalue is not null))     
         end as strVal, 

         case when count(*) > 1 then 
            jsonb_agg(intvalue) filter (where intvalue is not null) 
         else 
            to_jsonb(min(intvalue) filter (where intvalue is not null))     
         end as intvalue, 

         case when count(*) > 1 then 
            jsonb_agg(booleanvalue) filter (where booleanvalue is not null) 
         else 
            to_jsonb(bool_and(booleanvalue) filter (where booleanvalue is not null))     
         end as boolVal
  from eav
  group by id, attributename
) t
group by id;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
select id, jsonb_object_agg(att, value)
from (
  select id, 
         attributename as att, 
         case 
           when count(*) > 1 then 
               jsonb_agg(coalesce(stringvalue,intvalue::text,booleanvalue::text)) 
           else 
              to_jsonb(min(coalesce(stringvalue,intvalue::text,booleanvalue::text)))
         end as value
  from eav
  group by id, attributename
) t
group by id;
```

The inner select aggregates multiple values into an JSON array, single values into JSON scalar values. And the outer query then builds a single JSON value of all rows.

Online example: https://rextester.com/TLCRN79815

Comment: Thanks for your time. Sounds good. Are there are any differences when using json or jsonb in my case if the result set is very large?

Comment: JSONB is more efficient